# NamedList problem in solr

Tags: java, solr

Here i had added code below in which i had ArrayList Which contains values  and then i am adding that values to my named list

```
NamedList final1 = null;
NamedList<ArrayList<String>> result = null;
ArrayList<String> data=\\ It has values
result.add("Gender",data);
ArrayList<String> data1=\\ It has values 
result.add("Group ID",data1);
final1.add("Query",result);
```

But the code is not working. I don't know why this code is not working. CAN Any one guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: fyi, "final" is not a valid java variable name - it's a java keyword

Comment: sorry i had wrongly asked this question instead of final1 i type as final. In my code i had named as finalresult..... sorry to all. now while i am adding arraylist to namedlist . it shows nullpointerexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `final1` to be `null` and didn't initialize it before using it.

So, when the code:

```
final1.add("Query",result);
```

executes, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you should initialize `final1` before using it. Something like:

```
NamedList final1 = new NamedList();
```